# What does the _val_: do in Solr and what is it for?

Tags: function, solr

I am new to Solr and I am trying to get my head around it. I can't for the life of me find any decent documentation for Solr. I've checked on the official page to see what `_val_` does but it doesn't explain it well.

If someone can explain it here and give examples of how it's used that would be great!

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information about "_val_". What are you doing where this comes into play?

Answer (score 7):

`_val_` is a hook provided by Solr for [`FunctionQuery`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery). You can pass in a function to the query to manipulate the score of a document.

Ex:

```
_val_:"recip(rord(myfield),1,2,3)"
```

[Refer here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) for the SolrQuerySyntax